# Dynamic GroupBy LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, expression-trees

Suppose I have a class

```
public class Item
{ 
    public int Field1{get;set;}
    ……
    public int FieldN{get;set;}
}
```

And I want to use group by like this;

```
Collection.GroupBy(selector“Field1,…,FieldK”)
          .Select(x=> new Item
              {
                  Field1 = x.Key.Field1,
                   …
                  FieldK= x.Key.FieldK,
                  FiledK+1= x.Sum(x.FieldK+1),
                  ….
                  FiledN= x.Sum(x.FieldN)
              };
```

How can I do this using Expresions Tree

Comment: are you sure what you want is the expression tree?
maybe you are looking for the **Query Syntax** of the linq statements you wrote using **Method Syntax**. Is this the case?

Comment: How big is `N`?

Comment: I think he wants to dynamically generate the fields used for grouping, which would require expression trees to programatically create the expression passed in the first parameter to `GroupBy`.  Some clarity from OP would be helpful in knowing for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow mahul!
What you want can be achieved like this:

```
var a = from item in collection
        group item by new {item.Field1, ... , item.Fieldk} into newGroup
        select new {
            Field1 = newGroup.Key.Field1
            Field2 = newGroup.Key.Field1
            ...
            FieldK+1 = newGroup.Sum(x => x.FieldK+1),
            ...
            FieldN = newGroiup.Sum(x => x.FieldN)
         }
```

make sure to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) too. There are good examples there .

Comment: `FieldK+1 = newGroup.Sum(x => x.FieldK+1),` will not work.

Comment: @DStanley This is just a pseudocode and should be replaced with the real code .
That is a notation to represent the (K+1)th field.

Comment: I understand that - how do you propose to implement that when K is not known?

Comment: @DStanley aha, I see. You are right in case K is not specified in compile time. 
But the op has not mentioned that he is trying to generate query dynamically.
I'll remove this answer if the OP's provides us with more clarification.

Comment: by K+1 i meant Next Field. my code is just an imaginary. Anyway, I solve my problem for the Grouping using Expression Tree, Now I am working on GroupJoin.